# Compiling C++ with Soundtouch

Tags: c++, linker, soundtouch

I am trying to write an application in C++ that uses soundtouch libraries. I am unable to figure out what library to use to link it with. Specifically, I am using SoundTouch.h.

I have this code compiled in C as well. The library I used then was lsoundtouch4c to link. I have not been able to find information on this any where else, so help is most welcome.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code written in C++ that uses sound touch libraries can be linked using the following libraries:

```
/usr/local/lib  
SoundTouch
```

So, the linking in a makefile will look something like this:

```
main: <some-dependencies>
     g++ <your g++ options> <object files> -L/usr/local/lib -lSoundTouch
```

Sriram.